# Displaying dimensions of each image as caption or label

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to loop through each image on a page...

For each image, get the height and width of the image, and display it as either a caption or label or free-text, located above or below or next-to the image. The display method (caption, label, free-text) and location don't matter, whichever is easiest is OK.

I know how to loop through all "image" elements and call a function and get the image dimensions (image.width, image.height). I just need to know how to display that information on the page near each image. I'll keep the display text simple, just "width x height", like: `220 x 144` or `220w x 144h`.

I'm not worried about making sure the images are loaded, because I'll execute the loop after "onload", or actually, more likely, by a button press.

Here is some sample code:

```
function doit(){
  var o,p,q,r,s,t,u;
  o=document.images;
  p=o.length;
  if(p<1){
    alert("No images!");
    return 0;
  }
  for(q=0;q<p;q++){
    r=o[q];
    s=r.src;
    t=r.width;
    u=r.height;
    y=t+'w X '+u+'h'
    /* OK, I now have the image height and width. */
    /*I need to know how to insert 'y' as a 'caption' near each image. */
  }
}
```

For test purposes... I have wrapped this code as a Javascript function like:

```
javascript:(function(){function doit(){var o,p,q,r,s,t,u;o=document.images;p=o.length;if(p<1){alert("No images!");return 0;}for(q=0;q<p;q++){r=o[q];s=r.src;t=r.width;u=r.height;y=t+'w X '+u+'h'/* OK, I now have the image height and width. I need to know how to insert 'y' as a 'caption' near each image. */}}})()
```

so I can put it in a "bookmark" to try it on any page I am viewing. I'm hoping to do this using only javascript (without JQuery).

Comment: You asked: _is it just image.width, image.height?_ So you haven't tried it?

Comment: Where are you stuck? You seem to have the right idea here, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Jeffman - I haven't tried it yet, because I don't know how to take that info and display it.

Comment: @KevinFegan Well you have two very different things here.  1. Get an image dimensions and 2. Display data from Javascript on your page.  Most of your question is about how to get image dimensions, which you know how to do.  So is your question really about how to display values you in javascript on a webpage?

Comment: @AlexWayne - Really the biggest, and probably the only problem is to find out how to display the info near each image.

Comment: @KevinFegan We aren't going to do this for you, so give it a shot, and put a simple self contained example on http://jsfiddle.net/ and link it in your question with a description of exactly which part you are stuck at.  A more specific question with your code that shows the attempt so far will get you much better help.

Comment: @AlexWayne - I don't know why you are focusing on the wrong parts of my question. As I said in my question, I know how to write the basics of the code, but I can't show an example of the part I don't know how to write, so I didn't think it would be necessary to include any code. I have added some sample code that may make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/qBDqe/)

**HTML**

```
<img src="/" alt="Image"/>
<img src="/" alt="Image"/>
<img src="/" alt="Image"/>
<img src="/" alt="Image"/>
<img src="/" alt="Image"/>
<img src="/" alt="Image"/>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
  width: 250px;  /* For demo purposes */
  height: 200px; /* For demo purposes */
  border: none;
}
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 12px 12px 0;
  border: 1px solid #555;    
}
.img-wrapper span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

  $('img').each(function() {

    var image = $(this),
        imgW  = $(this).outerWidth(),
        imgH  = $(this).outerHeight(),
        size  = '<span>'+imgW+'px X '+imgH+'px</span>';

    $(this).wrap('<div class="img-wrapper">'+size+'</div>');

    $('.img-wrapper').css({ width: imgW + 'px', height: imgH + 20 + 'px' });
  });

});
```

Comment: Can this be done with plain JavaScript/DOM manipulation, without JQuery?